# How to iterate through dictionary key with values driving conditional statements

Tags: dictionary, conditional-statements, filtering

I'm trying to iterate through some dictionary keys and values to filter a dataframe.

Here is my code so far.

```
def sectorfilter(sector_dict):
   global tickerlist
   for sector_dict.keys():
      if sector_dict.values() == False:
         tickerlist = tickerlist[tickerlist['Sector'] != sector_dict.values()

sector_inputs = {'Energy':False, 'Basic Materials':False, 'Industrials':True, 'Utilities':True, 'Health Care':True, 'Finance':True, 'Telecommunications':True, 'Consumer Discretionary':True, 'Consumer Staples':True, 'Technology':True, 'Real Estate':True}

sectorfilter(sector_inputs)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't filter the dataframe at all when the Energy and Basic Materials sectors should be removed.

Am I doing something particularly wrong with this function?